# How to hide removable disk by its label in Win7 Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How to permanently hide specific removable disk by its label in the Windows 7 Explorer not to be able access it when it's connected to my PC? I mean hide the disk in the Computer folder window and under the Computer drop-down list in the left sidebar of the Explorer.

I'm interesting in any possible ways including workarounds with system files, the Registry Editor and so on, but with the proviso the hiding can't be canceled by standard user, only in administrator account or with typing administrator's password.

ps. Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

We can hide specific removable disk by modify the register:

Step1: Open "Run", type "regedit.exe", click "OK".

Step2: Locate to

HKEY-CURRENTUSER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer.

Step3: Right click on the right side of the blank space, select "New - DWORD value".

Step4: Set the following three value:
1.Value Name: NoDrives.
2.Type: REG_DWORD.
3.Choose "Decimal" for the Base section.
4.Value Data: for example, we can set the value data of C disk as 4.
[image]

Step5.Restart our computer and our drive in hidden now.

If we are supposed to get the drive back, change the value to "Zero", or we can even delete the ‘NoDrives’ registry key.

I search this article, there are four ways to hide a drive in Windows 10. It is **through Disk Management, using Group Policy, through Windows Registry or by using Diskpart command in CMD**, we can refer the other three ways to hide specific removable disk.

[How to hide a Drive in Windows 10/8/7](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-hide-a-drive-in-windows)

Comment: As I understand, you mean my specific disk must always have the same letter and its number according to your link at the end? If yes, it's not the solution because there may be different devices connected to my PC, so if I disconnect for example my flash drive, the letter of the disk to be hidden will be changed. Is there a way to specify not a disk letter or number, but the disk label like "CANON_DC"?